# How to add a class with django form lable

Tags: html, django

How to add a class to django form label?

I have `<label for="id_first_name">First name:</label>` when I use `{{ form.first_name.label_tag }}`

I want to add `class="col-sm-4 control-label"` with label.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use form **init** method to call class

```
class YourForm(forms.Form)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'your_class'
```

Comment: I tried
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control' def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

I think this is used for adding class for input fields, I want to add a class for <label></label>

Comment: you can do same thing for label too. instead of fields use label thats all

Comment: if you want to add calss in your label in your template then call your label like {{form.field.label}}

Comment: sorry i used like {{ form.first_name.label_tag }} but i get an output like
<label for="id_first_name">First name:</label>
i want to add class="col-sm-4 control-label" with label

Comment: @VineethaKD: AttributeError: 'Form' object has no attribute 'labels'